# 755 permission of uploaded files

Tags: file-upload, permissions

I just want to know, if giving 755 permission to an uploaded file is a security problem. If someone upload a malicious file, will the execute permission be a problem?

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4714841/1069464), he is giving the file that permission. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the application, but generally it is "yet another factor that must be taken into consideration". In addition to checking the content and type of uploaded files, saving uploaded files outside of web server's executable directories and a multitude of other necessary precautions.

For detailed information refer for example to the [OWASP article on file upload](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload).

In practice however attacks could utilize a web server's user account, so it is more a concern your disabling `x` permission for all users rather than limiting just `other` as one comment under the referenced answer suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it all depends who owns the file/who runs the upload file... if is a malicious file and root runs it.. then no matter what permissions you have you are screwed :)  but I will use 750 if I was you. Also you can try to chroot your app, and that directory.

Comment: Why 750 instead of 640?